# oracle pivot,I don't know how many columns I have

Tags: oracle

[image]

[image]

How do I get this result? I don't know how many columns I have.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the use of PIVOT in Oracle. To get columns dynamically, you may have to use XML.

Comment: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_GNZ3LQPJ0K6RTD1NEEPNRQT0R.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your language in your screenshot. So I am using the `employees` table.
To generate column names at the runtime you may use `PL/SQL` `DBMS_SQL` package.
Here is the syntax for pivot but groups are created for remaining columns that are not present with the pivot clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
PIVOT(
    COUNT(employee_id)
    FOR department_id
    IN(60, 70)
);
```

[image: Output for the below query]
But if you want to pivot for some selected columns use a subquery in the `FROM` clause to limit the columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT employee_id,
           department_id
    FROM employees
)PIVOT(
    COUNT(employee_id)
    FOR department_id
    IN(60,
    70)
);
```

[image]

Here I am adding `JOB_ID` column in the query then the query will be grouped by `JOB_ID`

[image]

Similarly, you can write a query which includes only the columns you want from the table, but keep in mind those columns which are not used with `PIVOT` clause will be grouped automatically.